# jqGrid - Make column name label different from its corresponding field name

Tags: jqgrid

I.e. I want the field name "Firstname" to have an asterisk in it to denote a compulsory e.g. "*Firstname", but I don't want the main grid column  name to have asterisk in it too.

Clicking the Edit button pops up a form with the asterisk it in, but this also appears on the Grid when viewing the resultset.

Can someone advise on a way around this?

Thanks.

This is what I've currently got that doesn't solve my problem.

```
colNames: ['*Firstname']
colModel:[{ name: 'Firstname', index: 'Firstname', label: 'Firstname', width: 150, editable: true, editrules: { required: true} }]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set some prefix or suffix for the column name in the Edit form you should use corresponding [formoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#formoptions) instead of the `colNames` or `label` property in the `colModel`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I eventually used this


    colModel: [

{ name: 'Firstname', index: 'Firstname', width: 150, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *' }}

]

Comment: @Kwex: You are welcome! The `formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *' }` is very close to what you need.

Comment: `formoptions: {label:'*First Name'}` seems to be what is needed for this.

Comment: @Joseph: Sorry, but what you try to implement? what is your problem? any why `formoptions: {label:'*First Name'}` is what you need? `formoptions` are documented [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#formoptions), but I can't say what is the best way in your case if I don't know the requirements. `name` property will be used to build some `id` attributes and it would be not good to use [meta-characters](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) like `*` inside of ids. So one should use '*' only inside of some labels in the form.

Comment: I'm giving a code snippet for the original question based on what you recommended in your answer.  Using the label field in form options is exactly what the original poster is looking for.

Comment: @Joseph: OK! I'm glad that the answer could be helpful for you.